# How to update data in same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem trying to dynamically update data in a table. I am using a timetable module. In that, each day has 7 periods. For example, on Monday the first period is "English" and second period is "Maths".

However it won't update the same row. Instead, "English" is added in one row and "Maths" is added in another row. How can I solve this problem?

_table.html.erb

```
<table class ="table">
    <tr class = "info">
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Periods/Timing</th>
        <th></th>

    </tr>
    <% @timetable.each do |i| %>
        <tr class = "info">
            <td>*****</td>
            <td><p><%= i. period %></p><p><%= i.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")  %>&nbsp;to&nbsp; <%= i.end_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")  %></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><%= i.day %></td>
            <td><%= i.subject.subject %></td>
        </tr>   

    <% end %>
</table>
```

In view, Day -> Monday, Subject -> English is in one row, Day -> Monday, Subject -> Maths is in another row. Subject Maths was not updated in the same column.

Comment: You might want to mark some of your previous questions accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you have two `<tr>`s in the loop. It should be like this:

```
      <% @timetable.each do |i| %>
        <tr class = "info">
          <td>
            <p>
              <%= i. period %>
            </p>
            <p>
              <%= i.start_time.strftime("%I:%M %p") %> &nbsp;to&nbsp;
              <%= i.end_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")  %>
            </p>
          </td>
          <td><%= i.day %></td>
          <td><%= i.subject.subject %></td>
        </tr>   
      <% end %>
```

Comment: The Day Monday was repeated in another row.if day Monday was already present, subject will be added in same row.This my problem.